# jQuery radio button "checked" attribute not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, checked

I'm trying to add text to a div based on which radio button a user checks, but it ends up firing the "else" block no matter which attribute is checked, and displaying "female" every time.

Please help!

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" id="male" value="male">Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" id="female" value="female">Female<br />

$(".gender").change(function () {                 
if ($("#male").attr("checked")) {
        $("#content").text("male");
    }
    else {
        $("#content").text("female");
    }
});
```

Comment: I suppose you can't set the value directly

Answer (score 7):

Use `.prop('checked')` rather than `.attr('checked')`.  The latter is based on the HTML attribute which will always be false because it is not in the DOM.  `.prop` can be used to check property changes that may not be visible in the DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xxuh8/

Answer (score 5):

Your code would have worked until `jQuery 1.8` or lesser. http://jsfiddle.net/Dnd2L/

In latest versions `.attr` is for the attributes which was defined in the HTML and `.prop` is mapped to the properties of the element which is dynamic and returns the current value.
http://jsfiddle.net/Dnd2L/1/

More information about `attr` and `prop` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/297641

Answer (score 0):

You don't particularly need an if since your radio buttons are grouped and no multiple choices are possible.

You might want to use this instead:

```
$(".gender").change(function () {                 
    $("#content").text($(this).val());
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lsg6/

Answer (score 0):

or if your radios don't have a class use

```
$("input[name='gender'][checked='checked']").val();
```

to get the value of the checked radio. To change which is checked, put the value of the cbx you want checked in val() i.e., `...val("male");`